# How to Calculate CGPA

Tags: mysql, sql

Dear i want to Calculate CGPA at to end of Each Semester
How to Calculate CGAP of All Semseters

```
SELECT SNO, SEMESTER, SUM(CRH), SUM(GP), SUM(GP)/SUM(CRH) GPA
from STUDENT_EXAM
WHERE SNO = 1
GROUP BY SNO, SEMESTER;
```

-

```
Student No  Semester    Credit Hours    Grade Point GPA CGPA
1       1       18      60      3.33    
        2       6       15      2.50    
        3       18      22      1.22    
        4       18      38      2.11    
        5       6       12      2.00    
        6       18      58      3.22    
        7       18      55      3.06    
        8       6       21      3.50
```

Comment: What's the formula for CGPA?

Comment: Use GROUP BY SNO only to get data for all semesters.

Comment: The select query and the output of the query provided are not in sync

Comment: There are different technique for different university and board. Suppose we take an example of CGPA 8.00. Here the percentage would be 75%. You can google it for more information "CGPA to Percentage "cgpa to percentage converter" and follow the results.